# Ошибка при попытке присвоить переменную и потом сохранить в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть кусок кода в котором сначала переменной типа list присваивается значение и затем должно сохранятся в txt файл но при попытке сохранения выдает ошибку UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sv' referenced before assignment

```
    sv[0] = ui.l1.text()
    sv[1] = ui.l2.text()
    sv[2] = ui.l3.text()
    sv[3] = ui.l4.text()
    sv[4] = ui.l5.text()
    sv[5] = ui.l6.text()
    sv[6] = ui.l7.text()
    sv[7] = ui.l8.text()
    sv[8] = ui.l9.text()
    sv[9] = ui.l10.text()
    sv[10] = ui.l11.text()
    sv[11] = ui.l12.text()
    sv[12] = ui.l13.text()
    sv[13] = ui.l14.text()
    sv[14] = ui.l15.text()
    sv[15] = ui.l16.text()
    sv[16] = ui.l17.text()
    sv[17] = ui.l18.text()
    sv[18] = ui.l19.text()
    sv[19] = ui.l20.text()
    sv[20] = ui.l21.text()
    sv[21] = ui.l22.text()
    sv[22] = ui.l23.text()
    sv[23] = ui.l24.text()
    sv[24] = ui.l25.text()
    sv[25] = ui.lp1.text()
    sv[26] = ui.lp2.text()
    sv[27] = ui.lp3.text()
    sv[28] = ui.lp4.text()
    sv = open (sv[28], 'w') 
    sv = map (lambda x: x + '\n', sv) 
    sv.writelines (sv) 
    sv.close ()
```

Comment: А где вы присваиваете `sv` пустой список для начала? Ну, это помимо того, что у вас в `sv` и список и файл одновременно, как в ответе написали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sv = open (sv[28], 'w') 
sv = map (lambda x: x + '\n', sv)
```

у вас `sv` и указатель на файл и список, что в файл надо записать?

вы или крестик снимите или трусы наденьте

```
file = open (sv[28], 'w') 
sv = map (lambda x: x + '\n', sv) 
file.writelines (sv) 
file.close ()
```

Comment: в файл надо построчно записать список тоесть каждые элемент списка на отдельной строке

Comment: @QQSem, я понимаю - но вы когда создаете файл через `open`, то перетираете свою переменную `sv` - присваивайте результат операции `open` другой переменной (я в конце своего ответа показал код)

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён я просто использовал другой метод записи:

```
places = ['Text']

with open('listfile.txt', 'w') as filehandle:  
    for listitem in places:
        filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```

А также метод чтения:

```
places = []

with open('listfile.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    for line in filehandle:
        currentPlace = line[:-1]
        places.append(currentPlace)
```